# CSV file uploaded to php mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I was trying to make a page where the user can upload csv file instead of inputting so many data to save in the database.

```
<?php
     $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
     mysql_select_db("csv",$conn);

     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        if($file == "")
        {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('No File Selected!');
            </script>
            <?php
        }   

        else
        {
        $handle = fopen($file,"r");

        while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false)
        {
            $username = $fileop[0];
            $name = $fileop[1];
            $address = $fileop[2];

            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`username`,`name`,`address`) VALUES ([$username],[$name],[$address])");
        }
        }
    }
?>
```

When I click submit button, nothing happens. It just refresh the page and it does not save from the database. I also check the SQL query from the version of my phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Strings should be surrounded by quotes.

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`username`,`name`,`address`)
VALUES (
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "',
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "',
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($address) . "')");
```

Also this code can be used for sql injection. Also the mysql functions are deprecated and you should switch over to using PDO.

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers